# Install a particular version of a package and related packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm attempting to install Erlang from the Erlang Solutions repository (scroll down to *"Installation using repository"* on the Erlang Solutions [download page](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html).

The current version is Erlang/OTP-20.0-rc2, but I want Erlang 19.3. If I try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install erlang=1:19.3-1
```

...I get an error as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 erlang : Depends: erlang-diameter but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: erlang-eldap but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: erlang-ic-java but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: erlang-src but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: erlang-examples but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I know that I can resolve this by using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install erlang=1:19.3-1 erlang-diameter=1:19.3-1 erlang-eldap=1:19.3-1
```

But that requires that I know, ahead of time, what the dependent packages are.

How do I *programmatically* (i.e. in bash) solve this in the "general" case? At least for Erlang/OTP, anyway?

Note: I know that I can `sudo apt-get install esl-erlang=1:19.3` (except that it'll upgrade unless I use [fkraiem's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/926030/158095)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is not correct, because even if you install version 19.3 manually, it will be upgraded to version 20* the next time you run `apt upgrade`. What you should do is create a file `/etc/apt/preferences.d/erlang` with the following contents

```
Package: erlang* esl-erlang
Pin: version 1:19.3*
Pin-Priority: 501
```

This tells Apt that, for all packages whose name contains `erlang`, versions starting with `19.3` should be preferred over all other versions, even newer ones. Then a simple `apt install erlang` should install version 19.3 with all its correct dependencies.

Comment: This doesn't work: (1) the ESL deb adds a similar statement to `/etc/apt/preferences`; (2) even with that removed and this added, `apt-get install erlang` still complains (same error as in question).

Comment: It needed `1:19.3*` for the version number. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe All right, I wasn't totally sure about the `1:`... You made other changes; are they also necessary?

Comment: Unsure, but that's what I ended up with, and it works. I didn't want to spend too much time reverting each bit. My package glob is slightly more restrictive than your regex, and https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html suggests (to me; I could be misreading it) that a priority >= 990 was correct.

Comment: Indeed your version only catches packages whose name *starts* with `erlang`; in particular it does not catch `esl-erlang`, so Apt may want to upgrade it, which could cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Remove previous Erlang versions/packages:**

```
$ sudo apt-get purge erlang esl-erlang erlang-base erlang-crypto erlang-eldap erlang-inets erlang-mnesia erlang-os-mon
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get install -f

$ sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/erlang
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ sudo rm -f erl
$ sudo rm -f erlc
$ sudo rm -f epmd
$ sudo rm -f run_erl
$ sudo rm -f to_erl
$ sudo rm -f dialyzer
$ sudo rm -f typer
$ sudo rm -f escript
$ sudo rm -f ct_run
```

**2. Add the repository entry manually:**

- To get Ubuntu codename type `$ lsb_release -c`. In my case it's **xenial**.
- `$ sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and add following text at the end of the file:

```
# Erlang Solutions
deb https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu xenial contrib
```

- Create a file **/etc/apt/preferences.d/erlang** :

```
$ sudo touch /etc/apt/preferences.d/erlang
$ sudo nano /etc/apt/preferences.d/erlang
```

with the following contents:

```
Package: erlang* esl-erlang
Pin: version 1:21.3*
Pin-Priority: 501
```

where *21.3* is the version of Erlang/OTP.

**3. Install Erlang:**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/erlang/bin/erl /usr/local/bin/erl
```

**4. Check installed Erlang version:**

```
$ erl -eval '{ok, Version} = file:read_file(filename:join([code:root_dir(), "releases", erlang:system_info(otp_release), "OTP_VERSION"])), io:fwrite(Version), halt().' -noshell
```

Comment: Hello, can you please explain why you linked the two files in third step above? This is the line in question: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/erlang/bin/erl /usr/local/bin/erl`